# How do I know to where my object is going when I drag and drop between the columns

Tags: javascript, angular, drag-and-drop, ng2-dragula

dragula and I am facing with an issue that is, how to know which column the object is going by the ID or something like that.

I do have 3 columns, but when I move an object between them I got the JSON information that doesn't tell me source column and target column, I need this information to send to the backend and save into the database.

This code below is an example that I am trying to do on my real code.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7k1bcq

This first JSON is an example that what I am receiving in console

```
{name: "listagem", el: {…}, target: {…}, source: {…}…}
el: HTMLLIElement
item: Object
name: "listagem"
sibling: HTMLLIElement
source: HTMLUListElement
sourceIndex: 0
sourceModel: Array[1]
target: HTMLUListElement
targetIndex: 1
targetModel: Array[3]
__proto__: Object
```

This second JSON is what I am expecting to receive to treat the data before to send to backend.

```
{name: "listagem", el: {…}, target: {…}, source: {…}…}
el: HTMLLIElement
item: Object
name: "listagem"
sibling: HTMLLIElement
source: HTMLUListElement
sourceIndex: 0
sourceModel: Array[1]
target: HTMLUListElement
targetIndex: 1
targetModel: Array[3]
sourceColumn: 0
targetColumn: 1
__proto__: Object
```

sourceColumn and targetColumn are the fields that I am trying to track

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get this is to use one JSON and rearrange everything in this. Finally you can get all information from them.

But of course you can use dragula services to get this data.

You can subscribe `.drag` event and get information about `source` from this.

```
        this.dragula$.add(this.dragulaService.drag('ITEMS')
            .subscribe(({name, el, source}) => {
                console.log(source); // information about source group
            })
        );
```

And to get information about target column you can use event `.drop`:

```
        this.dragula$.add(this.dragulaService.drop('ITEMS')
            .subscribe(({name, target}) => {
                console.log('target', target);
            })
        );
```

To use events you need only create new `Subscription` like this: `this.dragula$ = new Subscription();` and `.add` new subscription.

If you need more information, feel free to ask.

EDIT---

ready part of code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DragulaService } from 'ng2-dragula';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs/internal/Subscription';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  dragula$: Subscription;
  listas = [
    {
      nome: "Lista 1",
      id_lista: 1,
      itens: [
        { item: 'Lapis' },
        { item: 'Borracha' },
      ]
    },
    {
      nome: "Lista 2",
      id_lista: 2,
      itens: [
        { item: 'Maca' },
        { item: 'Banana' },
      ]
    },
    {
      nome: "Lista 3",
      id_lista: 3,
      itens: [
        { item: 'Doce' },
        { item: 'Chocolate' },
      ]
    }
  ];

  constructor(private dragulaService: DragulaService) {
    this.dragula$ = new Subscription();

    this.dragula$.add(this.dragulaService.drag('listagem')
      .subscribe(({name, el, source}) => {
        console.log('source', source.childNodes, source.parentElement.className);
       })
    );

    this.dragula$.add(this.dragulaService.drop('listagem')
      .subscribe(({name, target}) => {
          console.log('target', target);
      })
    );
  }


}
```

Comment: Hello, I implemented the events but the return is not what I expected.  https://angular-7k1bcq.stackblitz.io, returns html elements

Comment: I think that your problem is misunderstanding this console.log - in nature it's not a HTML but Node from DOM. Browser display it as an HTML because it's a browser nature. But of course you have an access to DOM elements. I updated my answer,  so you can get all `source.childNodes` or `source.parentElement.className`. 
From this two Node elements you can build what you need - all information is in this data, but of course you didn't get exactly your JSON from a question, but I think you didn't expected it.